# Linux - process's stack size

Tags: linux

In Linux, does a process have a limited stack size? That is, can the sum of stacks of it's functions not be more than a fixed size? If it is fixed, how is that size determined, and could it be set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340093/how-is-stack-size-of-process-on-linux-related-to-pthread-fork-and-exec

Comment: The `ulimit -s unlimited` sets the stack size unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that by default, normally the limit for process stack in Linux is 8MB, this cam be changed with *ulimit*.

The actual value can be obtained with:

```sh
$ ulimit -a | grep stack
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
```

You can get more info from *ulimit* man page, or review this question that explains how stack size is assigned to every process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407204/program-stack-size