# Memory consumption for threads

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

How will the memory consumption vary in these cases, there is a Process containing 1 thread and there is a Process containing 0 thread.

Comment: A process cannot have 0 thread. A main thread is required to actually execute code (at least on mainstream OS).

Comment: @JérômeRichard you don't need the thread if you are not executing the code, so a process can have 0 threads, when it doesn't do anything yet (typically when the operating system is still loading the program into memory)

Comment: During this time, the processes is certainly not be really created. Once created the _start function of the libc is called. Linux needs at least 1 thread per process in its kernel scheduling data structure. I may not be ready/active but it is created (the linking part is done by the user part and in a regular user thread). In C/C++, killing this main thread cause the process to be killed on Linux. On Windows, the program is loaded using multiple threads actually, AFAIR the behaviour is the same than linux once the libc entry point is called (but IDK about non-c/C++ programs or DLL-like stuff)

Answer (score 2):

While this question is too broad to answer, a thread typically need to save its stack, which is anywhere from a few KBs up to 1MB depending on the exact code executed inside the thread.

This is talking only about native C threads, other implementations might save extra data but it's usually safe to assume a thread will stay below 1 MB for most programming languages, and when in doubt just profile the program at hand.

Edit: according to Jérôme, the max memory of the thread stack is 2 MB on linux systems instead of 1 MB for windows.

Comment: On my system (Debian Linux), it is 2 MiB and AFAIK this is pretty common so I would say 2 MiB for the upper range.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Linux doesn't allocate stacks for new threads. It's the program's responsibility to allocate space for a new thread's stack before the application calls [`clone3()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html). (Also, the size of the "main" thread's stack is implicit in the layout of the executable file.) If you've got a program that allocates 2 MiB of stack for each new thread, and if you didn't explicitly specify 2 MiB, then that number must be a default in some programming language or library that you are using.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Interesting. I was focusing on C/C++ and it appears this is indeed done by the libc/libstdc++ during the call to `_start` for the main thread (based on environment variables) according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709030). That being said, for new threads, the standard (low-level) way of creating them on Linux is to use pthread which define a default stack size independently of the language (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340093) quoting the documentation). It is 2 MiB by default on x86_64 platforms (if `RLIMIT_STACK` is unlimited).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I haven't used POSIX threads in a good long time, but it looks like you can override the default stack size by first applying [`pthread_attr_init()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html), and then [`pthread_attr_setstacksize()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html) to a `pthread_attr_t` object, and then you pass a pointer to that object in to the [`pthread_create()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) call.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, of course. This is a *default* value, but users are free to configure that.